# How to pass a static value to IValueConverter in XAML

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, ivalueconverter

I would like to use static texts fetched from a web service in my WP7 app. Each text has a Name (the indetifier) and a Content property.

For example a text could look like this:

```
Name = "M43";
Content = "This is the text to be shown";
```

I would then like to pass the Name (i.e. the identifier) of the text to an `IValueConverter`, which would then look up the the Name and return the text.

I figured the converter to look something like this:

```
public class StaticTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            return App.StaticTexts.Items.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name.Equals(value)).Content;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then in the XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Helpers:StaticTextConverter x:Name="StaticTextConverter" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

...

<TextBlock Text="{Binding 'M43', Converter={StaticResource StaticTextConverter}}"/>
```

However, this does not seem to work and I am not sure that I pass in the value to the converter correctly.

Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: try `{Binding M62.ValueboxConsent, Converter={StaticResource StaticTextConverter}}`

Comment: Afraid it does not work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally found the answer. The answer was a mix between that of @Shawn Kendrot and another question I asked here: [IValueConverter not getting invoked in some scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11843551/746968)

To summarize the solution for using the `IValueConverter` I have to bind my control in the following manor:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Helpers:StaticTextConverter x:Name="TextConverter" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}, ConverterParameter=M62}" />
```

Since the ID of the text is passed in with the converter parameter, the converter looks almost the same:

```
public class StaticTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter != null && parameter is string)
        {
            return App.StaticTexts.Items.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name.Equals(parameter)).Content;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

However, as it turns out, the binding and thus the converter is not invoked if it does *not* have a `DataContext`. To solve this, the `DataContext` property of the control just has to be set to something arbitrary:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="arbitrary" 
           Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}, ConverterParameter=M62}" />
```

And then everything works as intended!

Answer (score 12):

The problem lies in your binding. It will check the `DataContext`, and on this object, it will try to evaluate the properties `M62` and `ValueboxConsent` on that object.

You might want to add static keys somewhere in your application where you can bind to:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source="{x:Static M62.ValueboxConsent}", Converter={StaticResource StaticTextConverter}}" />
```

Where M62 is a static class where your keys are located.. like so:

```
public static class M62
{
    public static string ValueboxConsent
    {
        get { return "myValueBoxConsentKey"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the static texts are very simple: A string identifies a text and all texts are simply held in a long list. That's the reason I use LINQ to retrieve it.
However, I have updated my question to be more explicit, please have another look. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but you need to bind to the correct value. And if its not defined on your DataContext object, then your value will always be unknown

Comment: So there is no way to just pass in some static string?

Comment: You can add a Property on your Converter, and pass it along like so: `<Helpers:StaticTextConverter x:Name="StaticTextConverter" MyProperty="Value" />`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a value converter, you'll need to pass the string to the parameter of value converter

Xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StaticTextConverter}, ConverterParameter=M43}"/>
```

Converter:

```
public class StaticTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            return App.StaticTexts.Items.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name.Equals(parameter)).Content;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is also one of the possibilities I have thought of. However, it does not seem to work. If I set a breakpoint in my converter implementation, it is not catched. I don't know if there is something wrong with my setup of the converter, but all other converters that I am using are working fine.

Comment: It seems to work only when inside a `<DataTemplate>`. However, I also need it to work independently of that. Any suggestions?

Comment: This should work regardless of in/out of DataTemplate. Can you provide a zip/pastebin sample?

Comment: Your answer is halfway there. I just posted an answer that solves my question. It's a mix between your question and another one. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:MyProj.Properties;assembly=namespace:MyProj"

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Resources.MyString}, Converter={StaticResource StringToUpperCaseConverter}}" />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. (This answer got into the 'Low Quality Posts' queue ;) .. )

Comment: `Mode=OneWay` or `OneTime` need to be added to the `Binding` if `MyString` is a const.