# How to bind content in WP7 button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, binding, ivalueconverter

I have earlier asked how to convert static values of `TextBlocks` using bindings and `IValueConverter` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11796930/746968).

Now I would like to do the exact same thing, but with buttons instead. But the problem is, that buttons do not have the `DataContext` property, so the `IValueConverter` is not invoked.

So how do I achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How about setting the

```
Button.Content.DataContext
```

?

EDIT: XAML sample fixed

```
<Button Name="mmmm" 
        DataContext="{Binding MovieContext}" 
        Content="{Binding Title}" />
```

Comment: Do you have a `xaml` example?

Comment: It seems I'm not allowed to have a property called `DataContext` on the `Button.Content`. Are you sure this is compiling?

Comment: @Zappel sorry, I was writing straight to SO so didn't test it first. I fixed the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons do have a [DataContext property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). All FrameworkElements do. Why not just set the datacontext of the Page that all of these are in? If you set the DataContext of the page to be a backing ViewModel, then every control will inherit that DataContext.